# Angular proxy.conf.js uses wrong gateway

Tags: angular, proxy, visual-studio-code, angular-cli, vscode-tasks

I have a large Angular application, in which several gateways must be defined.

I implemented this in my **proxy.con.js** file, adapted my **visual studio code tasks** and the **angular.json** file.

Nevertheless, for a specific API call, a wrong gateway is always used rather than the one defined for it.

**My proxy.conf.js looks like this:**

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var proxyConfig = [
  {
    context: '/api/**',
    target: process.env.gateway_1,
    changeOrigin: true,
    agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY),
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
  },
  {
    context: '/resources**',
    target: process.env.gateway_1,
    changeOrigin: true,
    agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY),
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
  },
  {
    context: '/api/v1/vehicles/**',
    target: process.env.gateway_2,
    changeOrigin: true,
    agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY),
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
  },
  {
    context: '/api/v1/vehicles**',
    target: process.env.gateway_2,
    changeOrigin: true,
    agent: new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY),
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
  }
];

module.exports = proxyConfig;
```

**The serve target inside the angular.json looks like this:**

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "my-ui:build",
    "port": 8080,
    "ssl": true,
    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
  },
 ...
```

The scripts part of the package.json looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --base-href=/ui/",
   ...
```

**And my visual studio code tasks inside the tasks.json looks like this:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "options": {
      "env": {
        "gateway_1": "https://gateway1.apps.de1.my-cloud.com",
        "gateway_2": "https://gateway2.apps.de1.my-cloud.com",
        "http_proxy": "http://localhost:3128",
      }
    },
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Start Application",
        "command": "npm run start"
      },
    ....
```

Only gateway_1 is used. For all calls, which must go over the gateway_2 I receive a 404. The CLI shows me also that the wrong gateway is taken.

> GET /api/v1/vehicles?Size=100&type=xyz ->
>   https://gateway**1**.apps.de1.my-cloud.com

Instead of

> GET /api/v1/vehicles?Size=100&type=xyz ->
>   https://gateway**2**.apps.de1.my-cloud.com

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure because I didn't really looked at it, but I think you should define your context from the more precise to least on

Right now, `context: '/api/v1/vehicles**'` matches `context: '/api/**',` too. So it take the first one.

Could you try that ?

Comment: @sheplu No matter if I change the order or remove one of the two configurations -> the wrong gateway is still used.